# WordPress Slider not working in Theme I created

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

my problem seems to be the problem of a lot of others, but no amount of googling for the past 6 hours could lead me to a working solution for people who want to make Themes from Scratch. The solutions out there are mainly for people who want to get a specific plugin to work with an existing theme.

I am trying to learn making a WordPress Theme from Scratch, and I was able to put one together using the following Tutorial: http://www.onextrapixel.com/2011/03/08/how-to-code-a-wordpress-3-0-theme-from-scratch/

It works great, but when I try to add a Slider using a Plugin, it won't slide.

Can anyone here help with some insight as to what I(And the tutorial) are missing so that the Sliders would work?

Please do not mind the placeholder images, they are not meant to infringe on the copyright of the artist. These were supposed to be the sliders but they won't slide.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Did you include all required scripts ( js, css, ect.. )

Comment: I don't think I did. If I were to do this, in which file (functions.php, header.php, index.php) would be the best place to put them? Don't these come built in with WordPress? Thanks

Comment: Need more information about the plugin to say that. What plugin you useing? How do you load it in your page ( in your template, with shortcodes or via widgets ).

Comment: I have tried Meta Slider, Soliloquy and a few other free Sliders. These work when using an existing template, even a free one. I loaded these by copying and pasting their folders into the wp-content/plugins directory and activated them through the admin panel. I tried each one once and they were the only plugins active during the time of testing, so it isn't a conflict in plugins either. Thanks.

Comment: Meta Slider you can intergrate in your own template useing the `shortcode` in your template. You can write the following code in *header.php* . ` echo do_shortcode("[metaslider id=123]"); `. 123 need to be replaced with the ID of the slider. Also make sure the `<?php wp_head(); ?>` is in your code.

Comment: I have tried this already, the slider appears but it isn't sliding. Thanks for the quick responses.

Comment: Do you have a live preview?

Comment: The design is hosted locally but I added a screenshot for your reference. Thanks!

Comment: From what I see is that scripts are not loaded. do you load `wp_head()` and `wp_footer()` in your template ?

Comment: please include all js and css files in header.php and give correct path of files which you have include in header

Comment: Based on the error, my guess is that I am missing some JavaScript file dependencies in the js folder. My Theme has no js folder. I checked other themes and each theme has different files in their js folder. Looks like I need to do some research on Wordpress file dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was the answer. After 2 days I finally found it.

All I needed to do was put the following in the footer.php file:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Then all of a sudden it worked. I found the answer after reading the entire following page of the WP Codex:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development